# Store a mapping of addresses linked to arrays of structs

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

How would I have the following data structure be saved in an Ethereum contract using solidity?

```
{
  address1 => [struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5],
  address2 => [struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5],
  address3 => [struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4, struct5],
  ...
}
```

The goal is for me to be able to easily access the array of structs associated to each user/address.

Comment: How to get the values from map? Map[msg.sender].pop??

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21836)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
contract test {

  struct my_struct {
    int a;
  }

  mapping (address=>my_struct[]) Map;

  function fill_map(my_struct struct1,my_struct struct2) internal  {

    Map[msg.sender].push(struct1);
    Map[msg.sender].push(struct2);

  }
}
```

Comment: How did you get this data by address(msg.sender) can you please show this?

Comment: i didn't get your question!!