# How do I get the number of elements in a mapping?

Tags: solidity

Is there a way for me to get the total number of elements in a mapping in Solidity?

Comment: Not unless you count it by yourself (increment after the creation of a new entry, decrement after the deletion of an existing entry).

Comment: Does this help? [Are there well-solved and simple storage patterns for Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13167/are-there-well-solved-and-simple-storage-patterns-for-solidity)

Answer (score 5):

You can't. There is no way to know how many entries there are in a mapping.

If you need to keep tract of the mapping's elements you can use a separate array which holds extra information about the mapping elements

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it as @Lauri mentioned. You can check how to do it manually in my answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/113002/83229).